# What is body.transform in Box2D?

Tags: python-2.7, drawing, pygame, box2d, transform

I am learning to use box2d (pybox2d for python actually) with pygame and in one of the examples there is the following function:

```
def my_draw_polygon(polygon, body, fixture):
    vertices=[(body.transform*v)*PPM for v in polygon.vertices]
    vertices=[(v[0], SCREEN_HEIGHT-v[1]) for v in vertices]
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, colors[body.type], vertices)
```

I have understood most of the code up until this point but I don't understand what body.transform is or why we multiply the vertices by it when we draw the shape.

What is body.transform and why is it important?

Answer (score 0):

The transform defines the position and rotation of the body within the world.
Here is a text out of pyBox2d source code:

> ```
>     The body transform for the body's origin.
>     To set it, you may pass in a new Transform() or a tuple of:
>         (position, angle)
>     Setting the transform breaks any contacts and wakes the other bodies.
>     Manipulating a body's transform may cause non-physical behavior.
>     @param position the world position of the body's local origin.
>     @param angle the world rotation in radians.
> ```

Comment: So why in the above code would I multiply the vertices of the polygon shape with it's body's transform in order to get coordinates suitable for drawing to the screen?

Comment: I don't know much about the pygame engine but it looks like its converting box2d vertices which are located in relation to box2d world origin using box2d distance units ( meters ) and transforms them to screen space locations, so the debug draw can draw the polygons at the correct locations on the screen and with correct scale etc.

Comment: I know that that it is converting Box2D world-space into screen space so that the shapes can be drawn by pygame, but I don't understand why we multiply the vertices by body.transform before we multiply by the PPM (pixels per meter).

Comment: I don't know python well enough, but I know Box2d quite well. The vertices are positioned in relation to the body, so that multiplication possibly will take the vertices from the local in relation to body coordinate system in to the box2d world coordinate system and then multiply by PPM to finally bring in to screen coordinates.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would have thought that such a thing would require addition though. Hmm...

Comment: the transform object overloads the multiplication operator to mean "apply transformation". Even if the transformation is just a translation with no rotation (which just adds an offset to the coordinates), you still apply that transform using the * operator.

Answer (score 0):

It overloads this function from box2d b2Mul

```
inline b2Vec2 b2Mul(const b2Transform& T, const b2Vec2& v)
{
    float x = (T.q.c * v.x - T.q.s * v.y) + T.p.x;
    float y = (T.q.s * v.x + T.q.c * v.y) + T.p.y;

    return b2Vec2(x, y);
}
```